# If return counter

Tags: javascript

I have some script in JavaScript that is checking files on my server and here is example what I need to do with numbers so that I can easy describe what I need to get:

```
var a = 0;

if (a >= 5) {
    console.log('a bigger that 5!');
} else {
  console.log('increasing a...'+a)
  a++;
    return;
}
```

What I would like from output is this:

Increasing a...0
  increasing a...1
  increasing a...2
  increasing a...3
  increasing a...4
  a bigger that 5!

So how can I return to if comparation from else... I need this to compare true or false... but I write here code with numbers.

I see that return does not return to if comparation so what I need to do?

Comment: Please take a look at some tutorials on the web. Making a loop work is basic JS, and covered in basically every single tutorial out there.

Comment: Is all this code inside a function?

Comment: I've chosen this duplicate target as a quick and easy one... If anyone knows of a better dupe link, i'll gladly change it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use a while loop.

```
var a = 0;

while (a < 5) {
    console.log('increasing a...', a);

    a++;
}

console.log('a equal to 5');
```

Comment: this works very nice..i see that i can put while true or false for my project and this works...one begginer question is how is this for cpu usage? For example i need to have a 10 000 value would this be cpu usage of 100% on quad core cpu? exists any lower cpu usage? I try to learn optimized functions..:)

Comment: The amount of time required ("runtime") is directly proportional to the number of loops ("iterations"). In this case, the algorithm is extremely trivial and can not be further optimized, but in many cases it may be possible. Take a look at "time complexity" if you're interested in learning more.

Answer (score -2):

You are looking for while loop,...

```
var a = 0;
while(true) {
  if (a >= 5) {
      console.log('a bigger that 5!');
  } else {
    console.log('increasing a...'+a)
    a++;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this,...

Comment: Why downvotes ?

Comment: You should avoid using `while(true)` when it's not necessary, you can just put the condition in  the while instruction, one mistake and you crash the browser.

Comment: Do you see mistake that would crash browser in this code? I cannot see one.

Comment: So let's use weird code everywhere with this kind of thought, why give name to variable when we can use letter, not really clear but we don't care because it work ? Why should i comment code ? No need to do it because it works ? 

I downvote because an answer is like a recommendation, and i don't recommend your code, you can just use `while(a < 5)`